# Reference artifacts uploaded by Maven Assembly Plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

We have configured our maven assembly plugin to create individual jars files that are uploaded to our local maven repo via the deploy plugin.

However we need to reference those jar files (the ones created by the assembly plugin) within other projects as maven dependencies. Any ideas on how we can accomplish that would be greatly appreciated.

**Update** For example :

```
-client (pom.xml - groupId=com.mycompany artifactId=client)
  |-src
    |-main
      |-java
        |-authentication
        |-billing
        |-reporting
```

This gets split up into 3 different jar files by the maven assembly plugin and publish to our local repo as :

```
-client-authentication.jar
-client-billing.jar
-client-reporting.jar
```

How do we reference client-authentication.jar as a dependency for another project without it having it's own pom file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to include the `classifier` in the dependency (your artifacts have a `version`, right?):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>client</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <classifier>authentication</classifier>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

But I need to stress that you are going **against** the *one artifact per module golden rule*, you should split your code into three modules.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add that local repo to your other project's poms

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>my-local-repo</id>
     <name>My companywide local repo</name>
     <url>{the actual url of your repo}</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

This being done, you can add the dependency to those artifacts in those same poms

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>{some.group}</groupId>
     <artifactId>{my.local.repo.artifact}</artifactId>
     <version>{some.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: The thing is that the there is only 1 pom file, so simply referencing the groupId & artifactId will only point to the main pom file and not the individual jar files generated by the assembly plugin.